# How can I control a Python script continuously with key inputs?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, raspberry-pi, robotics

I have created a Python script that can take commands from a pipe (named pipe1). You can find the Script on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2r1Eedhe).
I tested the script with this other script:

```
import sys

fw = open("pipe1", "w" )

fw.write('fd\n')
fw.close()
```

and it worked.

Now I want to control the script with another Python script, that could write in the pipe if I press `w`, `a`, `s`, `d` or `p` and display me the keys, that i press.

In this example I just want to print the keys that I press. I would later add the `fw.write` commands to write in the pipe, which I tested before:

```
def key_inp(event):
   print 'Key:', event.char
   key_press = event.char
   sleep_time = 0.030

while True:
    try:
        if key_press.lower() == 'w':
            print "w"
        elif key_press.lower() == 's':
            print "s"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'a':
            print "a"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'd':
            print "d"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'q':
            print "q"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'e':
            print "e"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'p':
            print "stop"

    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print('Finished')
```

My problem is, that the script that i wrote (and improved with a stackoverflow member) closes immediately when i open it.

Can anyone explain me why, and how i can fix it so that the script stays open the whole time until i interrupt it with Ctrl+c?

Comment: Where `key_press` comes from?..Is it the same in the `while` loop and  the in `key_inp` function?

Comment: The bit of code example you are providing, has a local variable which is unused and later on an unassigned local variable.
Could you edit with the actual example script you are trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This answer relies on installing the readchar module. You can install it via pip: `pip install readchar`.

The code you are trying to use has no functionality: you only define a function, but never call upon it. On top of that, it contains indentation errors.

Something along the lines of what you are trying to achieve, but with a dot as finish key:

```
import readchar

while True:
    key = readchar.readkey()
    key = key.lower()
    if key in ('wsadqe'):
        print 'Key:', key
    elif key == 'p':
        print "stop"

    sleep_time = 0.030

    if key == '.':
        print "finished"
        break
```